# SherlockFragmentActivity sometimes crashs when calling super.Create()

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

MyActivity is extended from SherlockFragmentActivity. And
I am using proguard. My project-proguard.tx does contain

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

This is the the stack trace. Strange thing is this does not look like a problem of my code. It traced to the support library.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        
ComponentInfo{com.mycom.mypack/com.mycom.mypack.MyActivity}:   
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@422ba150: Unmarshalling unknown   
type code 1670681840 at offset 72204
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@422ba150:    
Unmarshalling unknown type code 1670681840 at offset 72204
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2032)
at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1165)
at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:189)
at com.mycom.mypack.MyActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:296)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
... 11 more
```

====================

Below is the onSavedInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(), and part of onCreate(), there is some reading from savedInstanceState in onCreate() so I included it here.

```
private int recognize = 0;
private ArrayList<ToFree> to_free = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
......

if(savedInstanceState!=null)
{
  language_type = savedInstanceState.getInt("language_type");
  save_binary = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("save_binary", false);

  line_content =
    savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("line_content");
}

......

if(bitmap != null && savedInstanceState != null)
{
  final float[] m;
  final ArrayList<FloatPoint> flow;
  final ArrayList<FloatPoint2> filler;

  {
    m = savedInstanceState.getFloatArray("matrix");
    flow = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("reading_flow");
    filler = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("filler");
    show_flow = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("show_flow");
  }

 .....
}


protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
outState.putInt("language_type", language_type);
if(save_binary)
  outState.putBoolean("save_binary", save_binary);
outState.putBoolean("show_flow", show_flow);
if(line_content != null)
  outState.putParcelableArrayList("line_content", line_content);

if(to_free != null && !to_free.isEmpty())
  outState.putParcelableArrayList("to_free", to_free);
if(recognize != 0)
{
  outState.putInt("recognize", recognize);
  recognize = 0;
}

if(data != null && data.page != 0)
{
  outState.putInt("page", data.page);

  outState.putBoolean("running", data.running);

  outState.putInt("ret", data.ret);
  outState.putBoolean("rgb_set", data.rgb_set);
  data.page_saved = data.page;
}

if(bitmap != null)
{
  float[] m = imageView.get_matrix();
  outState.putFloatArray("matrix", m);

  ArrayList<FloatPoint> flow = imageView.get_point_list();
  if(flow != null && flow.size()>0)
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("reading_flow", flow);

  ArrayList<FloatPoint2> filler = imageView.get_point_pair_edit_list();
  if(filler != null && filler.size()>0)
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("filler", filler);
}

super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

to_free = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("to_free");

recognize = savedInstanceState.getInt("recognize", 0);
int page = savedInstanceState.getInt("page", 0);
if(page != 0)
{
  data = new DataNative();
  data.rgb_set = false;
  data.running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running", false);
  data.ret = savedInstanceState.getInt("ret", 0);
  data.rgb_set = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("rgb_set", false);
}
```

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with the Saving and Resuming state in dealing with Parcelables. Could you please post your model class code and the code you have in onSaveInstanceState and your onCreate.

Comment: I added onSaveInstanceState() code to the main post. I used a few ArrayList, and one float[]. Some of the retrieving is done in onCreate(), I don't know if that is a problem.

Comment: It looks like you are conditionally adding values to the bundle for your onSaveInstanceState which is more trouble than simply always writing and reading the values. I definitely suggest just always writing out all the variables you want to save. Additionally, all things have to be read in the order they are written in. It looks to me like that is not always the case. So if I save an int, then a string I have to read the int first then the string always. Lastly, does your list properly implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)?

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time. You are right, I found one mistake in one of my Parcelable implementation, one field was written twice. That's enough to cause serious problem. I know in Perlable implementation, the read and write order must be the same. Does this also apply to Bundle?

Comment: Nah, a bundle uses Name/Value pairs so as long as you have the correct Name you should be all set. Reading over what I wrote that was confusing, I meant with the Parcelable pieces.